# When does rehashing occur for unordered associative containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, unordered-set

I found this in the standard as the post-condition for the `rehash` function in unordered associative containers :

> Post: a.bucket_count() > a.size() / a.max_load_factor() **and** a.bucket_count() >= n.
>   (n being the number of buckets in the container)

Can I take the above to mean that an automatic rehashing is triggered when either of the above conditions is met for all implementations? Or, are implementations free to decide when to rehash and the above only pertains to the `rehash` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation shall keep the `load_factor() <= max_load_factor()` and `load_factor() == size() / bucket_count()`.  So automatic rehashing can occur during an `insert` to keep the load factor invariant.

Although the `load_factor()` can not exceed `max_load_factor()`, I don't think there is a guarantee that no rehashing will be done during an insert even if you can prove that this invariant will not be violated.

Definition for `max_load_factor` is:

> Returns a positive number that the container attempts to keep the load
>   factor less than or  equal to. The container automatically increases
>   the number of buckets as necessary to keep the load factor below this
>   number.